# PHP Class DB Connections

Tags: php, mysql, oop, classloader

I have a class which I'll like to include couple db routines instead of inline.

```
class Classica{

public $dbhost;
public $dbname;
public $dbuser;
public $dbpass;


__function construct(){
    //hook connectdb() upon contruct.
}

#connect to database
    public function connectdb($dbhost,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass){        

        $link = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
        if (!$link) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }else {
            //echo 'Connected Successfully to Database<br>';
        }
        @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
    } 

    #read database
    function readdb(){        
    }    
    #update database
    private function updatedb(){        
    }
    #close database connection
    function closedb(){
        mysql_close();    
    }

}
```

**config.php**

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dem';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
include('config.php');
include('classica.php');
$obj = new classica();

?>
```

The database connection details I will like to maintain on a separate config file which is included on document load.

**The problems I'm having:**

Retrieving database config values inside the class.
Trying to attach a separate database class to separate from parent.

Any suggestions of approach and/or solution.

Comment: you could search for PDO singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be do `include('config.php')` inside the connectdb function (or the function calling it). When you `include` a PHP file (remember to include `<?php` open tag!), the variables will become declared within the scope of the function doing the inclusion. So for example, __construct() (note that you have a typo) may be:

```
function __construct() {
    include('config.php');
    $this->connectdb($dbhost,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the config variables in the [global scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
public function __construct()
{
    global $dbhost, $dbname, etc... ;
    $this->connectdb($dbhost, $dbname, etc...);
```

Or use [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), its scope is global:

config.php

```
define('MYAPP_DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('MYAPP_DBNAME', 'dem');
```

and in your class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->connectdb(MYAPP_DBHOST, MYAPP_DBNAME, etc...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to read from a config file? Try 'parse_ini_file'. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php